# How is Sonar eclipse plugin connected to Sonar

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I'm just starting to do some research into Sonar, and I couldn't find much information on the eclipse plugin (Java).

- Why does Sonar plugin have to be hooked up to a server? Doesn't the analysis happen locally?
- How is Sonar plugin connected to the platform according to [this architecture overview](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing)?

Comment: This won't answer all your questions but a nice entry point is also the source code of the plugin:  https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does Sonar plugin have to be hooked up to a server? Doesn't the analysis happen locally?

Yes, the analysis does happen locally but the plugin needs to talk to server to download the quality profiles/rules associated with your project. Also the code analyzers (which do the actual work of analysis) are downloaded by the plugin on your machine and then called into for analysis.

> How is Sonar plugin connected to the platform according to [this architecture overview][1]?

When you say 'sonar plugin' I assume you mean the sonar eclipse plugin. The eclipse plugin sits with the Eclipse IDE and runs the analysis in 'preview' mode where no data is published to the server. You can think of this as just another sonar-runner which is integrated with Eclipse.